# How to remove the u from the dataframe columns before loading into hive partition table

Tags: hive, pyspark

How to remove t u from this dataframe, as I am not able to load the data into my hive table which is having partition based on ability_id.

Always getting Illigalargument error because of 'u'

```
>>schema = StructType([ StructField("ability_id", StringType(), True),
StructField("bid", StringType(), True),
StructField("bidtime", StringType(), True),
StructField("bidder", StringType(), True),
StructField("bidderrate", StringType(), True),
StructField("openbid", StringType(), True),
StructField("price", StringType(), True)])`  

>>df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(auction_data,schema)
>>df.registerTempTable("auction")
>>first_line = sqlContext.sql("select * from auction where auctionid=8211480551").collect()
>>for i in first_line:
>>   print i

>>Row(ability_id=u'8211480551', bid=u'52.99', bidtime=u'1.201505', bidder=u'hanna1104', bidderrate=u'94', openbid=u'49.99', price=u'311.6')
>>Row(ability_id=u'8211480551', bid=u'50.99', bidtime=u'1.203843', bidder=u'wrufai1', bidderrate=u'90', openbid=u'49.99', price=u'311.6')`enter code here`


sqlContext.sql(""" INSERT INTO TABLE dev_core_t1.PINO_KLANT_3 partition (abillity_id) SELECT bid,bidtime,bidder,bidderrate,openbid,price from temp """)
```

Comment: problem is not `u`. The problem is your special character `'` after u. Since `'` has a special meaning in hive. Thats why its not allowing to insert. `'u8211480551'` will be a valid data.

Comment: I have also tried to cast an string into int, and pass that one into the partition , and all such data doesnot have ', and they also dont have u, but while inser the data into partioned table was getting the same error -- Illigalargument error because of 'u'

Answer (score 1):

This issue is resolved, it seems any spark version lesser then or equal to 2.0.0.x.x.x will not work.

It only works with the spark version 2.1.x.x.x or higher.

Comment: Did you do any changes in the code or it worked as is in Spark 2.1.x ?